# Select and count in one query using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am returning paged, filtered results from some of my REST routes. If I simplify my code, it goes something like this:

```
var query = db.SomeTable.Where(row => row.SomeProperty > 42);

return new Result {
    data = query.Skip(skip ?? 0).Take(take ?? 25).ToList(),
    count = query.Count() };
```

This works, but it produce two queries to a SQL Server database: one that fetches the data, second that counts them. How to do this in one query without resorting to a hand-written T-SQL query?

Comment: What would a hand-written query look like that both selects the data (unaggregared) and counts the number of records (aggregated)?

Comment: You could run a "ToList()" at the end of the first row but then you would get all rows with SomeProperty > 42 from the database at first.

Comment: It just occurred to me that there's no way around generating two SQL queries for this. It will end up returning the count for each record

Comment: Jamiec: In T-SQL, one way is `WITH MyPaging AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS RowId, ... FROM ... WHERE ... ) SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyPaging) AS Total, * FROM MyPaging WHERE RowId BETWEEN 0 AND 20`

Comment: There are no hit on database for second query.

Comment: Navneet: I see two queries in my log.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var query = db.SomeTable.Where(row => row.SomeProperty > 42);

return query.Select (q => new{q, Total = db.SomeTable.Count()})
    .Skip(skip ?? 0).Take(take ?? 25).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

This is bad! It will end up returning the count for each record, but this is how you would do it if you wanted to do it with one database hit

Comment: Thats going to give a different result! With this the count would be of the `Take`n records, not the entire recordset as in the OP.

Comment: sorry. I've fixed that. Had to run it through linqPad to see the error of my ways! Plus, it's not a good idea attempting to get the count in one go. This is trying to carry across a pattern from SQL days